# How to make Siri perform a specific action in my App?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios10, sirikit

I want to integrate Siri in my app and make it perform specific actions i.e:

1- **open specific view**

2- **send feedback**

I searched about this functionality, but no useful answers were found.

anyone have tried use Siri like this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siri right now only works for certain 'domains' (see https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/).

If you app is in one of these domains you can trigger certain app functions through Siri. Depending on what kind of app you are working on you could theoretically use the Messaging domain to let users send you feedback.

You won't be able to use Siri to navigate through your app by voice but you might be able to trigger certain features.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So depends on your answer I can't open a specific view,  i.e "Siri please open app settings"? 

Siri just interacted with limit actions like send message, pause, play, stop, etc .. 
right?

Comment: @Rawan yes, there's a number of predefined behaviours for the different behaviours that can be controlled by Siri. "Send money to ", "Send a message to *user* with *appname" etc.